# Rounding floats in array not working to > 2 significant digits

Tags: python

An array of strings  :

```
values = []
values.append('49.189999')
values.append('48.360001')
```

Then I convert to float and attempt to round to 4 decimal places :

```
roundedValues = []  
for v in values : 
    roundedValues.append(round(float(v) , 4))

roundedValues
```

But values are just rounded to two decimal places :

```
[49.19, 48.36]
```

As I'm rounding the float value with 4 parameter, the number of digits rounded to should be 4 instead of 2 ?

Printing the values `print(float(v))` returns

```
49.189999
48.360001
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`round()` keeps the type as `float`, which means that both leading 0s left of the decimal point and trailing 0s to the right are not shown when the value is printed. If you need them to be retained then you will need to change the type.

```
>>> ['{:.4f}'.format(round(float(v), 4)) for v in values]
['49.1900', '48.3600']
```

Comment: 'If you need them to be retained then you will need to change the type.' we are both using float types so why your version not ignore the significant digits ? The fix is ' '{:.4f}'.format( ' ?

Comment: Uh, yes, that changes the type.

Comment: 'changes the type' is the type not float to begin with ?

Comment: It's not `float` to end with.